# Not sure why my code isn't working for Euler 12

Tags: python

The questions asks to find the first triangle number with over 500 divisors. I have an efficient code to find factors that works and another that finds triangle numbers but when I try to put them together in my code it doesn't give my the output I need.

```
factors = []
divisors = 0
num = 1
i = 1


def factor(n):
    global divisors
    step = 2 if n % 2 else 1
    for i in range(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, step):
        if n % i == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            factors.append(n // i)
    divisors = len(factors)

while divisors <= 5:
    num += i+1
    i += 1
    factor(num)
else:
    print(num)
```

I'm not sure if i have made a little error in my code or that my approach to the question is poor. My code outputs 6 instead of 28.

Comment: If you check your factor, you can see that values are added twice. This gives you more divisors.

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate numbers.

Check it before appending like this

```
if (i not in factors)
```

Full code:

```
factors = []
divisors = 0
num = 1
i = 1


def factor(n):
    global divisors
    step = 2 if n % 2 else 1
    for i in range(1, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, step):
        if n % i == 0:
          if (i not in factors):
            factors.append(i)
            factors.append(n // i)
    divisors = len(factors)

while divisors <= 5:
    num += i+1
    i += 1
    factor(num)
    print(factors)
    factors.clear()
else:
    print(num)
```

Comment: General tip: you can find easy formulas on the internet and learn more about the special numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number

Comment: Thanks for this I added factors.clear() to the while loop and got the correct answer